# Excel VBA works in Windows but not in Mac-OS

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The following sub runs like a champ on Windows version of Excel 2016 but I have a user trying to run it on her Mac and it's throwing an error. I don't have a screenshot of the error but when she sends it to me, I'll post it here.

I have written several other macros for this user, so I know she's not generally having any troubles with macros as such; It's specific to this macro. Is the code for generating PivotTables different in the Mac version?

```
Private Sub PivotCreate()
   Sheets("IndirectPivot").Select

   Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Indirect Import!R1C1:R1048576C4", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="IndirectPivot!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable4", _
        DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("IndirectPivot").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Funder")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("GL")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Class")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable4").PivotFields("Amount"), "Count of Amount", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Count of Amount")
        .Caption = "Sum of Amount"
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4")
        .ColumnGrand = False
        .RowGrand = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Funder").Subtotals = Array( _
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("GL").Subtotals = Array( _
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Amount").Subtotals = Array( _
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Class").Subtotals = Array( _
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("GL")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of Mac Excel?

Comment: Not using `Select`, and explicitly  stating what `Workbook` / `Worksheet` / `Ranges` / `Other object` the macro is working on is a good way to prevent macros from starting to behave in unexpected ways. I'm not saying it is the issue here, but I've seen a lot of trouble originating from such statements before.

Comment: I finally heard back from my client and I was able to identify the problematic chunk of code. The exception is being thrown when I try to create the PivotTable. So this block.


User is on Excel:mac 2011, version 14.4.7

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Indirect Import!R1C1:R1048576C4", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="IndirectPivot!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable4", _
        DefaultVersion:=6